# Code Issue i think -Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/App.php)

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I had to delete the `app.php` file and then restore it.

Now, I have a fully functioning back end, but the front end shows the below code.

> Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/App.php): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory in
> /home2/sportpat/public_html/clubdoncastershop/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
> on line 94
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/Model/App.php' for
> inclusion
> (include_path='/home2/sportpat/public_html/clubdoncastershop/app/code/local:/home2/sportpat/public_html/clubdoncastershop/app/code/community:/home2/sportpat/public_html/clubdoncastershop/app/code/core:/home2/sportpat/public_html/clubdoncastershop/lib:.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear')
> in
> /home2/sportpat/public_html/clubdoncastershop/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
> on line 94
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in
> /home2/sportpat/public_html/clubdoncastershop/app/Mage.php on line 670

Does anyone have an idea why it happened and how to fix it?

Comment: ist's `App.php`, not `app.php`. This could be the error. Also check if your file is readable. It should have permissions 644, or 664 in some hosting environments

Answer (score 0):

its look like permission issue,

May be some wrong permission cause this issue.

Login your server terminal via `SSH` and fire below commands to reset your file directory permission.

```
cd /YourMagentoRoot

chmod -R 644 ./*

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

chmod 550 ./mage
```

and finally clear cache by following command

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```